# How to use bootcov on a glm model (R)

Tags: r, statistics, linguistics

I'm using R to analyze linguistic data. I have a dataframe that looks something like this -

```
phoneme  onset  voice  ident
b        TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
b        TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
b        TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
b        TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
b        TRUE   TRUE   FALSE
... etc
```

I ran a `glm` on it, and now I need to use the `rms` library to run `bootcov` on the glm model. Problem is, bootcov doesn't seem to want to use the glm fit. It only wants to use lrms and whatnot. I tried doing an lrm model of my data, but when I ran bootcov on THAT, RStudio crashed. Multiple times.

Does anyone know how to get bootcov to work with glms? Is there something else I should be doing instead? I'm new to R (and statistics in general) and really only coming at this from a linguistics background.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bit long for a comment but is not intended as a full answer, also I have not used the`rms` package before.

From looking at the code of `bootcov` it also looks for the class `Glm`.  This is a wrapper function that calls glm.fit so should be ok. You also need to set x=TRUE and y=TRUE in your Glm call as `bootcov`expacts these.

Small example

```
# data
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(replicate(3,rbinom(100,1,0.3)))
names(mydf) <- letters[1:3]

# ------------------------------------------------------------
library(rms)

(mod1 <- Glm(a ~ b + c  , data = mydf , family="binomial", x=TRUE , y=TRUE))

# Check with glm
(summary(mod2 <- glm(a ~ b + c  , data = mydf , family="binomial", x=TRUE , y=TRUE)))

# Run bootstrap
set.seed(1)
b <- bootcov(mod1, B=200)
```